# How to loop to retrieve values from a dataset

Tags: sas

```
data aaa;
input x y;
cards;
1 2
3 4
;
run;

%macro aaa;
data _null_;
  set aaa;
  do i=1 to 2;
    if _N_ =i then do;
        call symput('Value',x);
        call symput('TagValue',y);
        %put &value;
        %put &tagvalue;
    end;
  end;
run;
%mend;
%aaa;
```

The results were 3 4,not 1 2 3 4. 
How to loop to retrieve values from a dataset? Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify what you expect.
Should `&Value` be `1 3` and `&TagValue` be `2 4`?
Do you expect  `&Value` and `&TagValue` to be arrays (which is impossible, but you could create `&Value1`, `&Value2` `&TagValue1` and `&TagValue2` and then write `%do suffix = 1 %to 2; blabla; %end;`)? Probably you should explain us what you want to do with them afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

In general, macro variables are not available until after the data step is complete so only the last values are available.

You can use the resolve function to get around this, but it depends on what you're trying to do overall.

```
%macro aaa;
data _null_;
  set aaa;
  do i=1 to 2;
    if _N_ =i then do;
        call symput('Value',x);
        call symput('TagValue',y);

        x=resolve('&Value');
        y=resolve('&TagValue');

        put x;
        put y;
    end;
  end;
run;
%mend;
%aaa;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only using two macro variables to save 4 values. 
The easiest way to do this is using the INTO: statement of proc sql([tutorial here](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi27/p071-27.pdf)).

Copy and paste the following code to get what I believe you want:

```
data aaa;
input x y;
cards;
1 2
3 4
;
run;

proc sql noprint;
    select x,y into:value1-:value2, :tagValue1 - :tagValue2
    from aaa;
quit;

%macro print_macro_variables;
    %put value   -  tagvalue;
    %put 1: &value1 -  &tagValue1;
    %put 2: &value2 -  &tagValue2;
%mend;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data aaa;
  input x y;
cards;
1 2
3 4
;
run;

%macro aaa;
data _null_;
  set aaa;
  macroVar = 'Value'||put(_N_,1.);
  call symput(macroVar,x);
  macroVar = 'TagValue'||put(_N_,1.);
  call symput(macroVar,y);
run;

%do sufx=1 %to 2;
  %put Value&sufx is &&Value&sufx;
  %put TagValue&sufx is &&TagValue&sufx;
%mend;

%aaa;
```

will result in

```
Value1 is 1;
TagValue1 is 2;
Value2 is 3;
TagValue2 is 4;
```

If your suffix exceeds 9, You will need to write `macroVar = 'Value'||strip(put(_N_,8.));`
See also http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi22/CODERS/PAPER77.PDF

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution.
[sas macro getvalue](http://www.datasavantconsulting.com/roland/Spectre/utilmacros/getvalue.sas)